# the trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed

Tags: windows, vmware-workstation, active-directory

I'm facing this issue with VMWare Workstation 7.1, with the guest being Windows 2008 enterprise edition with Active-Directory-based user login. Once I try to login with my active directory user, I'm facing the message 'the trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed'.

Answer (score 1):

I added and removed my machine from domain and it solved the problem.

Comment: this solves the problem temporarily. but the problem reappears again...
isn't there any permanent solution?

Comment: Try removing computer from domian, removing the computer account that is created when the VM joins the domain, then rejoin the VM.  Also might help to make sure your VM's networking is bridged and not NAT.

Answer (score 0):

This is a more general issue than just virtual machines.

Here is how to solve the same problem on a Windows 10 laptop.

This assumes that you can still log onto the computer when not connected to the network and that you have administrative privileges. (A special thanks to the IT professional in our building that helped me just now. This was his solution and it worked.):

1. From Control Panel -> System and Security -> System, click on the *`Change Settings`* link (requires administrative privileges).
2. Click on the `Change` button next to the text “To rename this computer or change its domain or workshop ...”
3. Click on the `Workgroup` radio button and typed in “WG” (or any dummy name) as the workgroup name.
4. Click `OK`
5. After it finishes associating the laptop with the dummy WorkGroup, repeat the process, except instead of changing to a WorkGroup, click on the `Domain` radio button and enter your domain name.
6. Log off and then back on again.